# How to get access to InitialContext in Jboss with maven?

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven-2, jboss7.x

I have tried looking for dependencies to import them but haven't had any luck thus far. I have found this one

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.naming</groupId>
   <artifactId>jndi</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

But maven can't resolve the dependency. I am trying to access a local session bean using JNDI.

I am trying to do something like this in my servlet

```
MyBean myBean = (MyBean) IntitialContext.lookup("java:module/MyBean");
```

and of course imported `javax.naming.InitialContext`

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the [JBoss-JavaEE-Specs](https://github.com/jboss/jboss-javaee-specs)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Anyhow If you would like to enable some of them, the [JBoss Java EE 6 Specification APIs](https://planet.jboss.org/post/jboss_java_ee_6_specification_apis) formal website also shows us as the following: -

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>    
    <!-- javax.enterprise -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- javax.persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- javax.ejb -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- javax.jms -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-jms-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ...
</dependencies>
```

I hope this may help.